# How to upload video to other YouTube channel by using YouTube API in Java or Android?

Tags: java, youtube

I want to upload my video to other YouTube channels. I am confusing the YouTube API sample code.so please give me some suggestion or code sample which are useful for uploading the video to other channels. please provide me sample code in java language .

The code sample is here:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
snippet.setDescription("Video uploaded via YouTube Data API using the Java library "
        + "on " + cal.getTime());

snippet.setChannelId("channelid");

// Set your keywords.
snippet.setTags(Arrays.asList(Constants.DEFAULT_KEYWORD, Upload.generateKeywordFromPlaylistId(Constants.UPLOAD_PLAYLIST)));
// Set completed snippet to the video object.
videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);


InputStreamContent mediaContent =
        new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
mediaContent.setLength(fileSize);


YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert =
    youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);


youtube
    .subscriptions()
    .list("snippet")
    .setMySubscribers(true)
    .setOnBehalfOfContentOwner("channel user id")
    .setOnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel("channelid")
    .setOauthToken("Oauthtoken create by api console").execute();

MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
```

but the code is not working fine.
and if i runt the code then i get following eror.

```
IOException

     com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
     {
       "code": 404,
       "errors": [
         {
           "domain": "youtube.parameter",
           "location": "onBehalfOfContentOwner",
           "locationType": "parameter",
           "message": "The specified content owner account was not found.",
           "reason": "contentOwnerAccountNotFound"
         }
       ],
       "message": "The specified content owner account was not found."
     }
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
         at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
         at com.google.ytdl.ResumableUpload.upload(ResumableUpload.java:176)
         at com.google.ytdl.UploadService.tryUpload(UploadService.java:177)
         at com.google.ytdl.UploadService.tryUploadAndShowSelectableNotification(UploadService.java:121)
         at com.google.ytdl.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:112)
         at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code or post the error which you get

Comment: yes this code given me error The specified content owner account was not  found

Comment: What do you mean by 'other channel'? Is it a channel of your own account?

Comment: no its not my account its other users channel. i have user id and channel id of other user and i want to upload the video from my account as well as other users channel.the video is uploaded from my site but its not uploaded by other user channel...so its possible to upload the video from both side

Comment: please guys tell me it is possible or not if yes then how .